# jquery menu script conflict

Tags: jquery, menu, typo3, expand

please, help who can. The site works on typo3. For the menu I use script: Simple JQuery menu by Marco van Hylckama Vlieg  and it works correctly:

```
jQuery.fn.initMenu = function() {  
    return this.each(function(){
        var theMenu = $(this).get(0);
        $('.acitem', this).hide();
        $('li.expand > .acitem', this).show();
        $('li.expand > .acitem', this).prev().addClass('active');
        $('li a', this).click(
            function(e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var theElement = $(this).next();
                var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                if($(parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                    if(theElement[0] === undefined) {
                        window.location.href = this.href;
                    }
                    $(theElement).slideToggle('normal', function() {
                        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                            $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                        }    
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && theElement.is(':visible')) {
                        if($(parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                            $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', 
                            function() {
                                $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                            }
                        );
                        return false;  
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && !theElement.is(':visible')) {         
                    $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', function() {
                        $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                    });
                    theElement.slideDown('normal', function() {
                        $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
};

$(document).ready(function() {$('.menu').initMenu();});
```

But when I connect a plugin jQuery ColorBox for images, probably scripts start clashing and the menu ceases to work and all submenus are expanded and I can't collapse it.

Maybe who will prompt as to resolve the conflict, where to look for the reason? Thanks/

Comment: refer jquery.noConflict()

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, most likely, that your TYPO installation is loading 2 instances of the jQuery library in one page. noConflict won't help you in that case, because that is for resolving conflicts between jQuery and other JavaScript libraries that use the $ namespace, like Prototype.

Whats happening when you load jQuery twice, is, that the the latter overwrites the first library with all it's plugins that had been loaded up to that point. TYPO3s has no management for Javascript libraries or conflicts. You may be in luck tho, if both extensions support t3jquery, which is an extension that tries to accomplish where TYPO lacks.

If they don't it means that you're pretty much on your own trying to figure out:

1) which extensions load jQuery

2) in what oder

and 3) set up all other extensions not to load jQuery, thus overwriting the jQuery instance that is already loaded.

Comment: Problem really was in loading of two libraries at once.I set up all extensions not to load jQuery and included it in a template just once. It helped! Thanks